# Powershell delete folders

Tags: powershell, scripting

How can I delete folders, not files, using PowerShell? I want to delete folders that are over 3 days old.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\test" |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) } |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_ -Force }
```

This doesn't work. I get no error and it does not delete any folders that are within d:\test.

Comment: Hi, what does not work ? It does not delete anything ? It produces an error message ? Please edit your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\test" |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) } |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

or:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\test" |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) } |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force }
```

Comment: You're welcome. The usage here is to accept the answer you prefer by clicking the check mark next to the answer vote.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your using powershell 4+ you don't need to do all the fancy filtering, the -file switch will give you what you need.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\test -File | Remove-Item
```

The above will give you what you need.

Comment: -File will delete files, not folders, like OP asked...?

Comment: Also the `-File` switch was introduced as part of 3.0